# What is Multiprocessor Communication in 8051, and how to use it?

Tags: microcontroller, serial, 8051, serialport

In 8051, one of the bit, SM2 or the D5 or SCON.5, is about "*Used for Multiprocessor Communication.*" I am not clear about it. I watched quite many tutorials or explanations about 8051 on YouTube, but no one explains how to use that what so called "*Multiprocessor Communication.*" The more or less I got explanation is the above comment: "*Used for Multiprocessor Communication.*" What is it about that Multiprocessor Communication and how to use it?

SCON: |SM0|SM1|SM2|REN|TB8|RB8|TI |RI |

Comment: @EugeneSh., how to use it? Yes, SCON used for serial communication. But for most serial communication, just involves SM0 and SM1, SM2 was never used at least as per what I found. So, what is it and how to use it?

Comment: @EugeneSh., actually I read many link on internet in my searching for that info. Both your links I have read. The first link even still opens since around 2 weeks ago. But there is no enough explanation about multiprocessor. Even in its datasheet, there is not enough info how to connect what is called master-slave communication. Especially, when it talks about master-slave, it is under the 8052 section (: **8XC52/54/58 HARDWARE DESCRIPTION**).

Answer (score 3):

I used this feature of the old 8051 UARTs many, many years ago.

It relies on a UART mode with 9 data bits instead of the usual 8 being sent between the start & stop bits. In that mode, the receiving UARTs are looking for the 9th bit being set, to indicate the other 8 bits were an address of the destination MCU. The UART only interrupts the MCU if the 8-bit address byte matches that of this specific MCU i.e. it then knows this data frame is intended for that MCU.

Instead of relying on my memory from so long ago, here is a description copied from the [Intel MCS 51 Microcontroller Family User's Manual](http://www.bitsavers.org/components/intel/8051/MCS-51_Users_Manual_Feb94.pdf) (page 123, labeled 3-14, in that 1994 copy kindly archived on Bitsavers):

> **Multiprocessor Communications**
>
> When the master processor wants to transmit a block of data to one of several slaves, it first sends out an address byte which identifies the target slave. An address byte differs from a data byte in that the 9th bit is 1 in an address byte and 0 in a data byte. With SM2 = 1, no slave will be interrupted by a data byte. An address byte, however, will interrupt all slaves, so that each slave can examine the received byte and see if it is being addressed. The addressed slave will clear its SM2 bit and prepare to receive the data bytes that will be coming. The slaves that weren't being addressed leave their SM2s set and go on about their business, ignoring the coming data bytes.

In the equipment I was working on, the slaves MCUs were all connected to the master  MCU via a shared RS-485 bus. Of course the MCU UART didn't know (and didn't care) what the physical interface was, but RS-485 is an obvious choice for shared serial connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that if you have a system with multiple processors, they can talk using this interface.

Seeing it's a serial port, makes sense to me.

Comment: As per my understanding, to communicate two devices (DCE), does not necessary be one kind of MCU. We may communicate them from different manufacturer. The data is sent in UART does not involve manufacturer info. It is just involve SM0 and SM1 as in the SCON above. I myself used to use Mode1 or Mode 2, which mode 2 involves parity check, P.

Comment: yes, so? That wouldn't stop anyone from labeling a serial port as "for communication with other microprocessors". Also, when you talked to some other device via a serial port, an easy 99% of times, there's a processor in that other device that you're talking to.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's just an UART with special 9-bit mode allowing for tagging a byte as command or data so all listeners can in hardware either ignore or receive data bytes but will get command bytes. 68HC11 has a similar feature that can be used for "address-mark wakeup".

Answer (score 0):

It is a mode that makes the UART hardware assist in receiving or ignoring bytes so that all receivers don't have to actively handle all bytes sent over UART.

Both the controlled and subdevices use 9 data bits for each byte, a bit like parity, but used for sending commands or subdevice addresses with the 9th bit set to 0, and data bytes with the 9th bit set to 1.

So all devices can listen for bytes with command or address, and ignore bytes with data. When some device decides from the command/address byte that it should receive this message, it then sets the UART into mode which makes it receive data bytes too, and when packet is finished, it can be set to ignore data bytes again.